# How to connect from azure devops release pipeline to web app created in another subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am creating a release pipeline on one of my Azure DevOps account. I want to release to the App Service created in my subscription under another account MYACCOUN@hotmail.com. Above the Azure subscription dropdown I click Manage and then I create a connection. I choose Azure Classic and then: 
1) if I choose Authentication Method: Credentials, I can see the following message:

"Specify a work or school account (for example @fabrikam.com). Microsoft accounts (for example @live or @hotmail) are not supported. Not recommended if Multi-Factored Authentication is enabled."

So I believe it won't work (and it doesn't)

2) if I choose Authentication Method: Certificate Based, I provide all the details, like Subscription Id, Subscription Name and Management Certificate and I click Verify, then the message says Verification Successfull. But when I save the changes I do not have this connection to choose on the list in the Azure subscription dropdown.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Don't use Azure Classic connections, use Azure Resource Manager connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy your app to an Azure resource (to an app service or to a virtual machine), you need an Azure Resource Manager service connection as Daniel mentioned.

You can follow below steps to create an Azure Resource Manager service connection.

**Project Settings-**->**Pipelines**--> **Service connections**-->**New Service connections**-->**Azure Resource Manager**-->**Service principal** (manual).

You will need to enter **Service Principal Id** and  **Service Principal key** for authentication. You can follow below tutorials to create an Azure service principal

[Use the portal to create an Azure AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal)

[Use Azure PowerShell to create an Azure service principal with a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-authenticate-service-principal-powershell)

Check document [Connect to Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops) for more information.